# Pgfplots does not recognise string data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Latex fails to compile the code below with the message

```
Could not parse input 'industry' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'ndustry'..
```

It seems that Pgfplots is not aware that the first column data are strings.  Is there any way to correct this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
category  cond othr
industry   202  72.8
transport    0 352
households 248  45.8
services    96  55.8
rest         0  30.3
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar stacked,yticklabels from table={\data}{category}]
\addplot table[x=cond,y=category]{\data};
\addplot table[x=othr,y=category]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ytick=data` for the `axis` and `y expr=\coordindex` for the plots.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
category  cond othr
industry   202  72.8
transport    0 352
households 248  45.8
services    96  55.8
rest         0  30.3
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar stacked,yticklabels from table={\data}{category},
  ytick=data
]
\addplot table[x=cond,y expr=\coordindex]{\data};
\addplot table[x=othr,y expr=\coordindex]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What if the string column is not the first one?

Comment: This would not change anything.

Comment: Oh I got it.  `\coordindex` refers directly to tick labels.

Comment: \coordindex refers to the row number of the table. And there is a ytick for each row with the text in column `category` as `yticklabel`.